# Как вывести значения ключа словарей которые находятся в массиве и передать в шаблон django

Tags: python, массивы, django, словари, dict

В интерпретаторе я делаю это так:

```
data = [{"red": "красный", "green": "зеленый", "blue":"синий"}, {"red": "красненький", "green": "зелененький", "blue":"синенький"}, {"red": "алый", "green": "темнозеленый", "blue":"небесный"}]
for d in data:
    red = d['red'] 
    green = d['green'] 
    blue = d['blue']
    print (red," | ",green," | ",blue)
```

как сделать то же самое в gjango, передать значения ключей построчно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В джанго мы передаем в html файл значение параметра context, которое содержит как раз словарь. Ключ - то, как мы будем именовать нашу переменную в html, значение -  ее значение)
**В файле views.py**

```
def index(request):
    data = [{"red": "красный", "green": "зеленый", "blue":"синий"}, {"red": "красненький", "green": "зелененький", "blue":"синенький"}, {"red": "алый", "green": "темнозеленый", "blue":"небесный"}]
    return render(request, 'index.html', context = {'data':data})
```

А далее в файле **index.html** нужно все принять и вывести

```
{%for d in data%}
{{d.red}} | {{d.green}} | {{d.blue}}
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Оказалось легче некуда :-)